# RTMP stream can't be played in flash

Tags: html, flash, video, rtmp

I have one RTMP stream, it can be played using VLC and FFmpeg. But can't be played in Chrome browser, so how should I debug this bug? I don't know anything about coding with ActionScript (Flash).

Comment: How is Flash involved? How are you playing this in Chrome? Since that's the issue, maybe show the code you've tried to display this RTMP video. Also provide a testable link to your video page and the RTMP link also.

Comment: I guess flash player and chrome doesn't support h264 cabac encoding.